# python xlrd - Retrieve Column index from sheet

Tags: python, xlrd

Hi I am just picking up xlrd. Regarding access to sheets and cell properties I am referring to [Xlrd Column](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Sheet.col_label_ranges-attribute)

The code from there shows.

```
for crange in thesheet.col_label_ranges:
    rlo, rhi, clo, chi = crange
    for rx in xrange(rlo, rhi):
        for cx in xrange(clo, chi):
            print "Column label at (rowx=%d, colx=%d) is %r" \
                (rx, cx, thesheet.cell_value(rx, cx))
```

So i thought i would just test printing out cell A1 from the sheet "Data", so I started to copy the above example.

When it completes however it errors at col_label_ranges:

```
inBook = xlrd.open_workbook('T:/AzReporting/DraftUtilization.xls')
outBook = xlutils.copy.copy(inBook)
for crange in outBook.col_label_ranges:
    rlo, rhi, clo, chi = crange
    for rx in xrange(rlo, rhi):
        for cx in xrange(clo, chi):
            print "Column label at (rowx=%d, colx=%d) is %r" \
            (rx, cx, outBook.cell_value(0, 0))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'col_label_ranges'
```

Also if I change col_label_names to be the worksheet name it also errors. I mus tbe missing something with this example. Maybe there is a better tutorial to follow?

```
for crange in outBook.Data:
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading or writing excel files? xlrd is for reading excel file and xlwt is for writing

I believe you are missing an intermediate step between

```
           inBook = xlrd.open_workbook('T:/AzReporting/DraftUtilization.xls')
```

and

```
           for crange in outBook.col_label_ranges:
```

You have to specify the sheet of the excel file

Even the example is labeled "thesheet"

I guess change

```
           for crange in outBook.col_label_ranges:
```

to

```
           sh=inBook.sheet_by_index(0)
           for crange in sh.col_label_ranges:
```

http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/10/pulling-data-from-excel-using-python-xlrd/